# How to show android GCM notification having single notification Id?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

I want to show news GCm notification.
After receiving multiple message i want to show like 3 unread msg,4 unread msg.
Please help how can i do
(sorry for bad english)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just count how many unread messages you have, build a notification and 
use the [a `NotificationManager.notify`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#notify(int, android.app.Notification)) there are two versions one that accepts a notification id and the other accepts a tag and an id,
for both methods if there is already a notification with the same id or with the (id,tag) any previous notification is replaced by the new one.

Take a look into [a this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html),
to see the available styles and patterns and use the one appropriated to your case, here's an example of how to do a `Big Text` or `Inbox Style` notification based on the number of messages

```
public static void updateOrSendNotification(Context context, String[] messages) {
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


    int count = messages.length;
    if (messages.length == 0) {

        notificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
        return;
    }


    //Intent to be launched on notification click
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
            null,
            context, MainActivity.class);

    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);


    int requestID = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, requestID,
            intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    String ticker = context.getString(R.string.new_notification_ticker);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);

    String contentTitle = context.getString(R.string.notification_text_style_title, messages.length);

    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_notification)
            .setTicker(ticker)                      // the thicker is the message that appears on the status bar when the notification first appears
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)  // use defaults for various notification settings
            .setContentIntent(contentIntent)        // intent used on click
            .setAutoCancel(true)                    // if you want the notification to be dismissed when clicked
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true); // don't play any sound or flash light if since we're updating


    NotificationCompat.Style style;
    if (count > 1) {
        NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();
        style = inboxStyle;

        mBuilder.setContentTitle(contentTitle);

        for (String r : messages) {
            inboxStyle.addLine(r);
        }
    } else {
        NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle bigTextStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
        style = bigTextStyle;

        bigTextStyle.setBigContentTitle(messages[0].substring(0, 10).concat(" ..."));
        bigTextStyle.bigText(messages[0]);
    }

    mBuilder.setStyle(style);


    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
}
```

This method assumes you call it every time with all the new messages your app has received,
since the NOTIFICATION_ID is always the same any previous notification will be replaced by the new one,
You can test it like this

`String[] messages = {
                "hi john how are you ?",
                "john you never told me if you'r doing ok !",
                "john lets go out"
        };
       updateOrSendNotification(this, messages);`

Answer (score 0):

From your question I assume you are trying to show stacked notifications (updating the current notifications)

Here is a detailed way of managing and updating notifications: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Managing

Multiple notifications:
[How to display multiple notifications in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18102052/how-to-display-multiple-notifications-in-android)