# Two parallel notifications from one app (android)

Tags: java, android, push-notification, alarmmanager, android-notifications

I would like to program an app, that sends two types of notifications. The user should see both of them.

Until now the notifications update each other, even if I change the flags of the pendingIntents.

That is my code:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

Intent intent = new Intent(this, Push.class);
Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, Push2.class);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
PendingIntent pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, intent2, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
AlarmManager alarmManager2 = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis()+10, pendingIntent);
alarmManager2.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis()+10, pendingIntent2);
```

Comment: Create 2 different notification builder objects.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18102052/how-to-display-multiple-notifications-in-android please check

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Create 2 different notification builder objects,

Example

**First Notification object**

```
Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context);

builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.some_img)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.some_big_img))            
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle(res.getString(R.string.your_notif_title))
            .setContentText(res.getString(R.string.your_notif_text));
Notification n1 = builder.build();
```

**Second Notification object**

```
Notification.Builder builder2 = new Notification.Builder(context);

builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.some_img)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.some_big_img))            
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle(res.getString(R.string.your_notif_title))
            .setContentText(res.getString(R.string.your_notif_text));
Notification n2 = builder2.build();

NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) context
        .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
```

Use the notification manager to show the notification

```
nm.notify(YOUR_NOTIF_ID, n1);
nm.notify(YOUR_NOTIF_ID_2, n2);
```

Please note that the reference code was taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8869647/4706252).