# Create multi Notification With Different Intent

Tags: java, android, notifications, local

I will try to create multi local notification every time with different parameters this is my code to create the notification:

```
 public void setNotficition(int Time,String ProdName,String ProdDesc,String ProdID){
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent("android.media.action.DISPLAY_NOTIFICATION");
    notificationIntent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");
    notificationIntent.putExtra("ProdName",ProdName);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("ProdDesc",ProdDesc);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("ProdID",ProdID);

    PendingIntent broadcast = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 100, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, Time);
    alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),broadcast);
}
```

This is my Code for BroadcastReceiver:

```
    @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String ProdName= intent.getStringExtra("ProdName");
    String ProdDesc= intent.getStringExtra("ProdDesc");
    String ProdID= intent.getStringExtra("ProdID");

    int ID = Integer.parseInt(ProdID);
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, NotificationActivity.class);

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(NotificationActivity.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationIntent);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);

        Notification notification = builder.setContentTitle(ProdName)
                .setContentText(ProdDesc)
                .setTicker("New Message Alert!")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify((int) ((new Date().getTime() / 1000L) % Integer.MAX_VALUE), notification);
}
```

Every time its take the last call

Comment: See my answer. hope it will work perfectly

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18102052/how-to-display-multiple-notifications-in-android

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notification `id` should be unique within your application.

> If a notification with the same `id` has already been posted by your
>   application and has not yet been canceled, it will be replaced by the
>   updated information.

```
NotificationManager notiManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);    
notiManager.notify(UNIQUE_ID, notification);
```

If you are using `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()` method, use different `requestCode` for different notification:

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent("android.media.action.DISPLAY_NOTIFICATION");
notificationIntent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");
notificationIntent.putExtra("ProdName",ProdName);
notificationIntent.putExtra("ProdDesc",ProdDesc);
notificationIntent.putExtra("ProdID",ProdID);

PendingIntent broadcast = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, REQUEST_CODE, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: i think its need to work but i get this Error: Error:(36, 62) error: incompatible types: AlarmReceiver cannot be converted to Context

Comment: I Passat my Context but it still work only the last push

Comment: did you used different request_code and different notification_id?

Comment: yap i put `(int) ((new Date().getTime() / 1000L) % Integer.MAX_VALUE)`

Comment: Use different request code >> PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, UNIQUE_REQUEST_CODE, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

Comment: I put a different int number every time

Comment: This is very helpful. But @FerdousAhamed can you explain why it should be  UNIQUE_REQUEST_CODE for PendingIntent.

Answer (score 2):

You can create multiple notification by changing notification id, everytime.

```
PendingIntent broadcast = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 100, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

The second parameter of the getBroadcast call is "notification id" (i.e. 100 in your case). Just use different different notification id in case of generating multiple Notifications.

Hope it will help u :-)

Comment: I get Error on "this" -Error:(36, 62) error: incompatible types: AlarmReceiver cannot be converted to Context

Comment: Pass your "context" object instead of "this".

Comment: :( I Passat my Context but it still work only the last push

Comment: Use new Random().nextInt(0, 1000) instead of 100. "for testing purpose only"

Answer (score 0):

A notification is created and linked to a id, this id can be used to modify or update on existing notification, weather you are changing the intent or just the behavior of the stack.